# Are there chess apps that allow users to record moves and do not include a chess engine?

Tags: engines, software

I have seen chess apps that work as a chess clock. Are there chess apps  that allow users to record moves and do not include a chess engine? The idea is to use the app during a chess tournament as a experiment. There are no economic prizes, so we consider the chance of cheating very small. Also, we are trying to educate people more than create world chess champions.

Comment: There no app that will record your moves for you.  When you see that in a tournament, they are using a special chess board and pieces.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Brian Towers posted an answer. The app exists! However, it seems that is available only for Android. The name of the app is Clono chess System.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I found one for iPhones! https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chess-score-pad/id518018730

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [Clono Chess System](https://clono.no/) runs on a tablet and has been [approved by FIDE](https://fide.com/news/1556) as an electronic scoresheet that can also broadcast the moves in the way that we see on Chess24.

Comment: I found one for iPhones! https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chess-score-pad/id518018730

Comment: I found another for Android. Blieb Chess Recorder Pro.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bliebapps.bliebchessrecorder.pro&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

For Android - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chess.clock&hl=en_US&gl=US&pli=1

For Apple - https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chess-clock-by-chess-com/id858039162

One from chess.com - https://www.chess.com/news/view/chess-clock-app-update

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know if I explain myself properly. My question is about a an app to record the moves, not about a chess clock. Of course, if there is an app that can do both, would be awesome.